# How to fill below 2d graphes in 3d with plot3()?

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, fill

i plotted a 3d plot with the following code, but with my own measured data:

```
Data    = rand(1000, 4);  % 4 Channels or more or less
Time    = 1:1000;
sData   = size(Data);
vSignal = 1:sData(2);
plot3(Time, vSignal(ones(1, sData(1)), :), Data);
view(-150, 60)`
```

Now I want to fill under the graphes I plotted.But it´s really important for me to be able to plot and fill below **multiple graphes**!
Do I have to use fill3()? I imported my data as a numeric matrix. I tried several ways but I failed.
Thanks for help.

Comment: Can you show us a diagram of what you want?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to use `fill3`:

```
for ii = 1:sData(2)
    fill3([Time,Time(end),Time(1)],ii*ones(1,size(Time,2)+2),[Data(:,ii);zeros(2,1)],ii*ones(2+size(Time,2),1),'EdgeColor','none');
end
```

I use the `for` loop since I create a patch for each plot separately (I call the filled-in area a Patch). For each patch, I need to give its boundaries, and `fill3` will fill everything in between. The boundaries are the exact points that you used in `plot3`, but in addition you need two more points on the x-y plane to close the patch (to make it a polygon). That is the reason I extend the vectors by 2.

Comment: Try adding the `hold on` command to the loop. Does that solve your problem?